# npm ERR! Error before running React and i cant fix it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web

hello I'm new to react anyway after making the necessary setups, after writing "npm start" it gave error how to fix this thanks in advance

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxBMW.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed changing your directory into your project folder before running `npm start`.

Try running `cd bruhdeneme` before `npm start` in the command prompt.

Comment: To add as well, use ````dir```` in the windows command line rather than ````ls```` which is for terminal.